# npm install --save-dev gulp : SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I am trying to learn node and npm and gulp and all but am running into this error.

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\davidb\desktop\testproject\npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am using gitbash instead of node because in my node i cannot even do node-v I have to use process.version to even get the version. And help with this would be greatly appreciated! I have been using http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-selfsignedcertinchain-and-npm to try to fix the issue but nothing is working.

Have also tried:

```
npm config set ca ""

and 

npm install npm -g --ca=""
```

Neither is working and I am still getting the error npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Windows's SSL-intercepting proxy is messing your npm up.

Checkout Github issue answer - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7519#issuecomment-97522305

Other option:

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

But this lowers your security.